# Powershell Script converted to EXE via Win-PS2EXE can be run manually but errors out when run as a scheduled task

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

The application moves files from one directory to another, runs an exe, and then moves files from one directory to another.

When I run the application manually it works as expected.

However, when trying to run it as a scheduled task I get the following error: 3762504530

[image]

I did some researching and it appears it may have to do with the application trying to run interactively even when there is no user actually logged in.

I have tried to suppress outputs but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Do you have any code that writes to the console? If so that maybe your problem.

Comment: I am using robocopy to move the files around, I am redirecting output to a log file though.

Comment: Ok without seeing your code I don't have any idea what maybe the issue, sorry ☹️

Comment: Read the stack trace - it says `MessageBox.Show()` is called - are you using `PS2EXE-GUI`? If not, please post the actual script

Comment: I am using PS2EXE-GUI something as simple as a powershell script with $text = 'Hello World' $text | Set-Content 'file.txt' when converted to an exe fails when I try to run it as a scheduled task, but works when I manually run the exe

Comment: I think the point @MathiasR.Jessen was making, is that ps2exe-gui is attempting to open a window, and since task scheduler runs as system, there is no way to display a gui. so it crashes. Even if you don't see one, it may still attempt to open a 0x0 pixel window

Comment: @RobertCotterman that was precisely the issue, I had to reconfigure ps2exe-gui to not compile a graphic windows program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking compile a graphic windows program (parameter -noConsole), remedied the error.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code i guess u use console output or similar...
If so change write-host to write-output or alias "echo" pipe it to log file if u want...
Also be sure that your script run "non interactive" (no prompts etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. There is a parameter within Win-PS2EXE that I had to uncheck that was compiling the powershell script as a graphic windows program.